# Bootstrap carousel with swipe (using touchSwipe) on two pages does not swipe

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, ratchet-bootstrap

I am building a mobile web app using Bootstrap and Ratchet. I have two pages, index.html and main.html. Each page contains one Bootstrap carousel with added swipe support using [touchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin). I'm testing using [Chrome Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#emulate-touch-events). The carousels on both pages are identical.

When I first load the index.html page, the swiping functionality on the carousel works. However, when I switch to main.html (via a link in index.html), I am unable to swipe the carousel in main.html. The same occurs when I load main.html first, and index.html second. However, when I refresh the page (on either page), the carousel works again...

I noticed that `$(document).ready(init);` is only triggered when I load the page for the first time, or refresh the page, but not fired when I switch to the other page, and I believe that is the source of the problem, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

I am seeing these error messages in the console:
`Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.`

`Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.`

**index.html**

```
<head>...
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ratchet.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var init = function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    $(".carousel-inner").swipe( {
      swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        $(this).parent().carousel('next');
      },
      swipeRight: function() {
        $(this).parent().carousel('prev');
      },
      threshold:0
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(init);
</script>
</head>
```

I have also tried to place these script tags after the `<body>` tags to no avail.

**Carousel code in index.html and main.html**

```
<!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="placeholderimg1.jpg" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption">...</div>
  </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="placeholderimg2.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">...</div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I've also tried [another Bootstrap carousel swipe library](https://github.com/avinoamr/bootstrap-carousel-swipe) (https://github.com/avinoamr/bootstrap-carousel-swipe) but experienced the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of jQuery I've been using:

```
$(".carousel").on("touchstart", function(event){
        var xClick = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    $(this).one("touchmove", function(event){
        var xMove = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) > 5 ){
            $(".carousel").carousel('prev');
        }
        else if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) < -5 ){
            $(".carousel").carousel('next');
        }
    });
    $(".carousel").on("touchend", function(){
            $(this).off("touchmove");
    });
});
```

No need for touchSwipe or any other plugins. If you need to adjust the sensitivity of the swipe adjust the 5 and -5. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--for bootstrap 5 not working solition-->    
<a id="left" class="left carousel-control" href="#bootstrap-touch-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">Previous</a>
<a id="right" class="right carousel-control" href="#bootstrap-touch-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">Next</a>
    
 

//swipe initial - in .js file
            $( ".carousel .carousel-inner" ).swipe( {
                swipeLeft: function ( event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount ) {
                    this.parent( ).carousel( 'next' );
                    $('#left').click(); //smartek.fixed.08.09.21 for bootstrap 5
                },
                swipeRight: function ( ) {
                    this.parent( ).carousel( 'prev' );
                    $('#right').click(); //smartek.fixed.08.09.21 for bootstrap 5
                },
                threshold: 0,
                excludedElements: "label, button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe"
            } );
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.